# Is it true that 

Tags: grammaticality, logic

Is the following sentence grammatically incorrect?

> Is it true that 1+1=2 ?

I know it is easier to say: Is 1+1=2 true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No; the sentence "Is it true that 1 + 1 = 2?" is perfectly grammatically correct.

In logic, there are tests that depend on being able to prefix almost arbitrary sentences with "It is the case that ..." or "It is true that ..." and if the result still makes sense, then certain properties hold (it is a declarative sentence which could be a proposition).  For example, you can test:

- The sun rises each day
- Go there!

The first is a declarative sentence like 'one plus one equals two' is a declarative sentence; it can be prefixed with "Is it true that" and it makes sense.  However, you can't say "Is it true that go there!" -- it is not a declarative sentence.

Comment: Indeed, the sentence is more likely than "Is 1+1=2 true" because the latter is likely to be confusing to hear.

Answer (score 1):

In ordinary usage, “is it true that 1+1=2 ?” and “is 1+1=2 true?” are both grammatically correct, synonyms, and largely interchangeable. The first sentence construction might be preferred because it places the mathematical expression at one end of the sentence. The second construction is particularly awkward when pronounced: when you hear “is *complicated mathematical expression* true”, it's hard to remember the verb that “true” is a complement of.

In mathematical usage, treating mathematical relations as verbs is frowned upon. A sentence like “is it true that 1+1=2 ?” looks ungrammatical because “1+1=2” looks like a mathematical expression (which happens to be a proposition), distinct from the English phrase “one plus one equals two”. In grammatical terms, “1+1=2” is equivalent to a noun group, it can't function as a verb. This is particularly true amongst logicians, since there is a step of semantic interpretation involved in going from “1+1=2” to “one plus one equals two”, and logicians are used to settings where this step is non-trivial. Even mathematicians and assorted practicioners who aren't logicians often consider “is it true that 1+1=2 ?” bad style.

Comment: I don't get your *“1+1=2” is equivalent to a noun group, it can't function as a verb"*. It's not functioning as a verb, grammatically or logically. It's functioning as a proposition. You can say *"Is it true that X?"*, where *X* is any proposition. This is grammatically and logically equivalent to *"Is X true?"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's the ordinary usage, but not the dominant usage amongst mathematicians. Ordinary usage tends to treat `=` as the verb *equals*, and therefore a logical proposition like `1+1=2` can be used as a grammatical proposition. It can also serve as a noun group, like any quote can be treated as a noun group (“‘green ideas furiously’ is meaningless.”). Mathematical usage tends to treat `1+1=2` as a mathematical expression or formula, `=` being just one of the symbols in the logical proposition, and this cannot be used in constructs like “Is it true that X?” where X cannot be a noun.

Comment: I'm not sure that's strictly a mathematical issue. The *proposition* is **1+1=2**, and I don't think deconstructing that proposition into sub-components, or translating arithmetic symbols into lexical ones makes any difference. If there's anything to take issue with, it's that logically we should probably either stick with *Is X true?* or go the whole hog and say *Is it true that X is true?"*. But however you put it, *X* is never going to be a "noun". It's a (potentially autonymous) statement.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In mathematical usage, `1+1=2` is not read formally as “one plus one equals two”, but rather as “the equality between the sum of one and one, and two”. “Is is true that the equality between …” is not grammatically correct, because “the equality between …” is not a proposition (in the grammatical sense) but a noun group.

Comment: I topped out at A Level maths, so I can't really argue that one much further. But I've done a lot of programming since then, wherein **1+1=2** is a *condition* (which evaluates to true or false). It is also a *statement*, and since we seem to be going nowhere useful, I'll leave that as my final statement on the matter! :)

Comment: @Gilles: I am sorry, but you're wrong about mathematical usage. In mathematical papers, mathematicians treat 1+1=2 **either** as a mathematical expression **or** as a grammatical proposition, whichever way makes the paper they're writing read better. They feel no compunction at all to be grammatically consistent about how they treat 1+1=2 in a mathematical paper.

Comment: Pulling the second edition of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* off my bookshelf (Rudin's textbooks are widely regarded as classics) and leafing through the pages, I find on page 10: "Since A = B, M is closed under the formation of countable (and also finite) intersections." (Here A and B are complicated expressions). This is ungrammatical unless you read it as "Since A equals B ...". On the other hand, on page 13, we have "... (a) follows from the relations A=B, C=D, and E=F. Here, for it to be grammatical, you have to treat these equations as verbless objects. Logicians may be different.